# HTML/CSS button with inverted half circle on both sides of button

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a button with inverted half circles on the sides.

I've tried creating a half-circle and placing it at the end of the button but the outcome doesn't look pleasant.

The outcome should look something like this:

[button with half circle at both end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wha9J.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use a combination of border-radius + CSS mask for the cutouts on the sides. However, if you want to reproduce the dotted inner border... then you're better off drawing the button using SVG.

Comment: Designing the button as SVG is probably your best option. You can use tools like Inkscape which is free and open source.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use CSS after and before Pseudo-Elements or else you can also use the CSS shadow property to achieve this kind of design. The below code shows with CSS after and before Pseudo-Elements.

https://codepen.io/Lijo_Chacko/pen/abLjEaw

**HTML**

```
<button class="circled-button">
  Button
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
  .circled-button
{
  background:#000;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0px;
  border:0px;
  padding:20px 15px;
  min-width:250px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
.circled-button:after
  {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9px;
    background:#fff;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
  }
    .circled-button:before
  {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-9px;
    background:#fff;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
  }
```